Period lattice of cubic twists of CM modular forms
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ be a CM field. Let $E_1:y^2=x^3+1/4$ and $E_p:y^2=x^3+p^2/4$ where $p\equiv 1\mod 3$ is a prime. Let $f_1$ and $f_p$ be the modular forms of $E_1$ and $E_p$. They are constructed from some Hecke characters related to cubic residue symboles of $K$. And
$f_p$ is a cubic twist of $f_1$ over $K$. Computer computation shows that the period lattice of $f_1$ is $\sqrt[3]{p}$ multiple of the period lattice of $f_p$. How to prove this fact ? It is not hard to prove the same relation for the periods of $E_1$ and $E_p$. By Glenn Stevens' conjecture in the paper Stickelberger elements and modular parametrizations of elliptic curves, $E_1$ and $E_p$ is the optimal quotient of $\Gamma_1(N)$, and the Manin–Stevens constant is 1, so the result for $f_1$ and $f_p$ should also be right. But how to prove this? Inspired by Stevens' proof for the quadratic twist case in section 5 of his paper, we can reduce to a weaker result that the period lattice of $f_p$ is contained in $1/\sqrt[3]{p}$ times the period lattice of $f_1$. But still, does anyone have any idea to prove this?

I believe you asked and deleted the same question a few days ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469720/period-lattice-of-cubic-twists-of-cm-modular-forms Can I ask why?  Is there a difference between these questions?

@Kimball. No difference, In the last version I miss the top tag number theory at first,  so I feel many pepole miss this question.  Then I post it again, and hope more experts can see it.

I understand your reasoning, but I think (not totally sure) that it might be frowned upon - e.g., see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116973/282702 - at least you shouldn't do this often.  (You should have been able to just add a tag to your old question.)

@Kimball I am sorry for that, but if some pepole miss the question at first, will they see this question again after I add the tags ?

It depends if they view by recent activity (for which edits like adding tags count) or by newest (when posted).  There are some (well at least 1) automatic mechanisms to bring attention to older unanswered questions on the site, but the main thing for you to do is offer a bounty.

@Kimball  I see, thank you very much for the answer.
